# Sum of Terminating Decimals

Tags: number-theory

If $k = \frac{1}{1+2x}$, where $x$ is an integer greater than $1$ and $k$ can be represented as a terminating decimal, find the sum of all possible values of $k$.

I know that there are a lot of values for k, because there is an infinite amount of terminating decimals. However, I need to find the sum of them. I tried listing most of them, but I got nowhere. Can anyone guide to me to find the solution for this problem?

Comment: Where did you find this question, because I think, that the sum diverges.

Comment: Alcumus from AoPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** The decimal expansion of
$$\frac{1}{n}$$
where $n$ is an integer only terminates iff all prime factors of $n$ are also prime factors of $10$ - that is, if
$$n=2^a\cdot 5^b$$
for some positive integers $a,b$.

Comment: I'm aware of this...How can I apply this?

Comment: It's nice thing I learnt today. Can you please give me a link so that I can understand the reason behind this fact?

Comment: This implies that $1+2x$ is divisible only by the primes $2$ and $5$, and since $x$ is an integer, $1+2x$ cannot be even. Thus $1+2x$ is a power of $5$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal

Comment: Ahhh... I see...So I would carry on finding the numbers...1/5 , 1/25, 1/125, and such

Comment: @Skupp Correct. Do you see the geometric series? :D

Comment: Oh thank you...First term is 1/5, common term 1/5...So total sum is 1/4.

Comment: That's right! :D

Comment: @Skupp If I answered your question, don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark}$!